# Why are auxilary constructors forced to call the main constructor in Scala?

Tags: scala

... and supply it with all necessary arguments even if they where not required for the auxiliary constructor. (Source: http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/) This is not the case in Java. What is the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 0):

Easy: if a parameter is not required, don't add it to the main constructor.

In java, all constructors also execute the code in the body of the class:

```
public class Foo {
   String x = mkX();
   public Foo() { System.out.println("THIS"); }
   public static String mkX() { System.out.println("THAT"); return "";}
}

new Foo(); // prints THAT, then THIS
```

The requirement in scala is actually more relaxed: your main constructor is allowed to have arguments.

Comment: "In java, all constructors call this()." That's not true. All constructors implicitly call `super()` unless they explicitly call a different constructor, but `this()` is only called if you explicitly write `this()`.

Comment: @sepp2k You are correct, I misspoke. Updated the answer to say it right

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, the primary constructor's parameters are available anywhere inside the class (among other reasons, so you don't have to repeat Java's `this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;`). If the parameter isn't used, it has no reason to be a parameter in the first place, so consider only the case where it *is* used. So if you could avoid supplying these parameters, and then got to the place where they are used, what should happen?

The compiler could use default values (`null`/`0`/`false`/etc), which is very likely not what the user wants. Or throw an exception, turning a compilation error into a runtime error, which is the opposite of what we want.